# How to calculate the expected value of distribution of independent trials with switch?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have $m$ coins which I can spend on cards with various stars.

One coin spent on card with star level $n$ gives $n$ points with probability $1/n$ and $0$ points otherwise.

Let $X_{n,i}$ represent the success indicator of $i$-th coin spend on $n$-star card, i.e. $X_{n,i} \sim BernoulliDistribution[1/n]$.

Let $T_{n,i}$ represent the points from $i$-th coin spend on $n$-star card, i.e. $T_{n,i}=n X_{n,i}$.

Let $B_{n,t}$ be the number of coins spend on $n$-star card to achieve total points of $t$ which requires $x=\left\lceil t/n\right\rceil$ coins, i.e. $B_{n,t}\sim PascalDistribution[x,1/n]$ where $B_{n,0}=0$.

Let $\mathscr{T}_{n,m}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}{T_{n,i}}=n\sum_{i=1}^{m}{X_{n,i}}=n \mathscr{X}_{n,m}$ where by setup $\mathscr{X}_{n,m}\sim BinomialDistribution[m,1/n]$.

I want to calculate the expected number of points after spending $m$ coins if I follow the following strategy:

- I start by spending on $n$-star cards until I achieve total points of $t$ or run out of coins.
- If I achieve the total points of $t$ in say $<m$ cards then I spend the rest on $\eta$-star cards where $1\leq \eta\leq n$

both over the full space and over the assumption that I don't lose completely.

I try to write the expectation I want to calculate as follows:

- $\mathbb{E}[R]$ and
- $\mathbb{E}[R|R>0]$

where $R=(n \left\lceil t/n\right\rceil+\mathscr{T}_{\eta,m-B_{n,t}})\mathbb{1}_{\{B_{n,t}\ \leq\ m\}}+(\mathscr{T}_{n,m}|\mathscr{T}_{n,m}<t)\mathbb{1}_{\{B_{n,t}\ >\ m\}}$.

Please help me find these expectations. Also guide may be I formulated the problem in a difficult way and it can be represented more simply.

Basically I am trying to figure out if don't lose completely (i.e. all $m$ coins results in no points), how much better off I will be by taking risk by spending coins on $n>1$ star cards.

Answer (score 1):

If each card purchased with one coin gives an expected number of $\frac{1}{n} n+\frac{n-1}{n}0=1$ point for all $n$,

then spending $m$ coins gives an expected $m$ points, no matter what cards are bought

Answer (score 1):

As noted in an answer already, all cards have the same expected value.

But the variance of $T_{n,i}$ is $E(T_{n,i}^2) - E(T_{n,i})^2 = \frac 1n n^2 - 1^2 = n - 1.$
That is, the higher-star cards have greater variance. So if you buy a set of $10$-star cards, for example, the variance of the total points will be greater than if you bought the same number of $2$-star cards.

If the goal is to get at least $t$ points (for example if $t$ points will get you to the next level in a game and less than $t$ means your character dies), then what matters is not the expected value but the probability of reaching $t$ points.

If $m > t$ you want to minimize the variance in order to maximize the probability of getting something near $m$ points and minimize the probability of getting much less than $m$ points.

If $m < t$ you (mostly) want to maximize the variance in order to minimize the probability of getting near $m$ points and maximize the probability of getting much more than $m$ points. (But of course you do not buy a card with more stars than you need to get from your so-far-accumulated score to $t$ points.)